# Heavy policing trains people not to try to respond. Is this intentional?

Tags: discussion, questions

I find that I'm being trained not to try to ask questions or provide information.  The eagerness, as it seems from here, to police honest questions and responses on grounds of form is amazingly aversive and since the reasons given rarely make sense to me, they reduce my willingness to try to participate at all.

I wonder whether it seems the same to others, whether the effect it's having on me is the one intended, and if the effect is not intended whether there should be different guidelines for policing.

Comment: Do you understand that the rules are there to ensure posts with high quality stay around? If you do, can you suggest a viable alternative?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users ?

Comment: Whether a question is honest or not really has no bearing on whether it is acceptable here.  In fact, dishonest questions (I guess that can only mean questions where the asker already knows the answer?) are specifically allowed.  So what you think should be allowed doesn't match up with the standards SE has specifically put forward.  There's lots of history involved in this (seven year's worth). You could spend half a day reading up on it here...  I guess, to answer your question, yes.  If you're not asking acceptable questions, you're going to feel pressure to go piss up a rope.

Comment: Well, you're only making general remarks and hence it's difficult to get to a good subjective discussion on this. What policies seem to stop you from contributing? What reasons are meaningless to you? What kind of policing are you talking about? etc etc. Answer those questions first, and then we can have a discussion.

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: @MMacD,  You might want to try asking that question on [quora.com](http://quora.com/) instead. In fact, you could even ask *this* meta question on [quora.com](http://quora.com/).

Answer (score 15):

We don't just want *any* question here. We want to build a knowledge base of *useful* and *good* questions.

Not every question falls in the rules defined in the help center of the site. If that is the case, people will down-vote and close your question, and eventually delete it.

Sometimes a question is not salvageable, no matter how much you try. A very good question on automobiles will be totally off-topic here, if you ask it here, it will get closed and deleted.

That means you have to put in some effort: check if the question is on-topic, make sure you follow the rules and advice in the help center. Tell what you have done and tried to answer your own question. If you do all that, your question will be received well.

Comment: You didn't answer my question(s), instead immediately defending the system, effectively telling me that my perceptions are wrong, that I'm not being trained, that the actions of the police are ipso facto correct.  One of the other two responders did the same thing, and someone even down-ticked my question(s).  What is that meant to convey to me?

Comment: @MMacD That you have some learning to do about StackExchange.

Answer (score 14):

> The eagerness, as it seems from here, to police honest questions and responses on grounds of form is amazingly aversive

This indicates that you are not interested in growing and changing, or even accepting constructive criticism. It appears you are attempting to use the site as an answer machine, where you put in a question, and get an answer.

If the question is well written, well researched, and shows good effort, then we are happy to provide that exact service.  Put in a good question, get a good answer.

If the question is poorly written, poorly researched, or shows little effort, then we will provide two services:

- Constructive Criticism (usually on how to improve the question, and how to ask good questions)
- An answer (may not be good, but this reflects the question quality more than the answerer's ability to provide a good answer.  Garbage in, garbage out, etc)

You are free to reject the constructive criticism, but the reality is that if you are a programmer who is unwilling to learn, grow, and get better as asking questions, then no - we don't want to encourage you to stick around. We don't mind if you do, but we're not going to go out of our way to provide an environment which will encourage people who ask poorly written/researched questions with little effort to stick around.

> [Is] the effect it's having on me ... intended

Yes, but only because you are rejecting the opportunity to learn and grow.  This will only irritate you if you assume the people commenting and editing are trying to hurt you.  The reality is that they are actually trying to help you, and if you assume good intentions, you'll find that the effect is different - not because the site changed, but because what you've decided to do with the feedback has changed.

If you don't want to change, and you want to assume people are malicious, feel free to come back when you have a question to be answered, and just use it as a question service (as long as the questions meet at least a minimum standard of quality).  It will work for that, and you can ignore the constructive criticism.

If you want to become a part of the community, stick around, try your hand at answering questions (which is probably the fastest way to integrate, since you'll see exactly why Stack Exchange has such a heavy focus on quality), and see if you can change the way you think about the feedback.

Answer (score 12):

**That desire** to show off a bit of what you know is one of the leading motivations of using Stack Exchange. It is that peer review through voting and comment that leads to better performance and personal satisfaction. A competitive drive to work just a bit harder and perform just a bit better than those around us makes us better at what we do. And we want to share the best of what we have by voting it to the top making it easily available to all.

That's how a top-tier programmer thinks.

**Having an aversion** to being peer reviewed and validated is going to make it really hard to be an accomplished programmer (or anything else you may do in the professional spotlight). Whether your code is getting slaughtered in a code review, or your stuff is being rejected from a project repository, people either meet that challenge by making sure their stuff is good enough to measure up… or they go home. But the people who continue to contribute do so because they love it; they thrive on it. It is how we get to work on the stuff we love while striving to get better at what we do.

There is a lot of garbage and bad information on the Internet without any vetting or scrutiny. When we say *we can do better,* people are either up to the challenge, or they're not.

So in that sense…

***…yes, it's intentional.***